# Exclude history fields from django simples history on to_representation method in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-simple-history

I'm using Django Rest Framework with django-simple-history and currently I would like to return the history modifications in my `Board` rest API, currently it is doing well but I would like to hide some fields. This is the currently output:

[image]

But, I don't need `id`, `history_id`, etc.

my implementation is the same of alexander answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736838/getting-rest-history-from-django-simple-history).
this is my currently serializers, where I put history on my Board model

```py
class HistoricalRecordField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.DictField()

    def to_representation(self, data):
        representation = super().to_representation(data.values())
        # i've tried to do it by deleting, but does't work well.
        del representation[0]['history_id']
        return representation


class BoardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    history = HistoricalRecordField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = '__all__'
```

But it does not seem the best way to do it.

If you have some hint about how to do it the correct way I would like to know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share the entire code of your serializer please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for `history_id` at least:

```
def to_representation(self, data):
        representation = super().to_representation(data.values())
        for hist in representation['history']:
            hist.pop('history_id')
        return representation
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `django-simple-history`, so they may be better solutions than mine.
 However, you can do this with a more DRF-friendly approach by simply using a **ModelSerializer** instead of a **ListSerializer**:

```py
class HistoricalRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = HistoricalRecords
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'share_with_company', [...]) # Only keep the fields you want to display here


class BoardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    history = HistoricalRecordSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'history', [...]) # Only keep the fields you want to display here
```

If you want to only retrieve the latest update, you could use a `SerializerMethodField` (documentation [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)). Remember to declare it in Meta.fields instead of 'history' (or rename your SerializerMethodField "history" if you want to keep this name):

```py
class HistoricalRecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = HistoricalRecords
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'share_with_company', [...]) # Only keep the fields you want to display here


class BoardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    latest_history = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_latest_history(self, instance):
        latest_history = instance.history.most_recent()  # Retrieve the record you want here
        return HistoricalRecordSerializer(latest_history).data

    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'latest_history', [...]) # Only keep the fields you want to display here
```

Keep in mind that I don't know much about this lib, so this should work but I cannot guarantee it's the best way to to it.

Comment: Your solution works very well, just one question before accept this answer: Using your approach, there is any way to show in the history field just the last update? history field show me all updates and it is what I need, but I'm just curious about the possibility to get just the last update (last object).